# Como obtener mejor performance con async/await c#

Tags: c#, asynctask, async-await

Tengo un método asíncrono que hace un llamado rest y este lo llamo en el appearing que es el método que se llama luego de que toda la UI carga en xamarin forms.

```
public async Task<Int64> obtenerPaginas(string company)
{
       Int64 total = 0;
       try
       {
           var client = new RestClient(
                    App.localEndpoint + "api/alertas/GetObtenerPaginas/" + company + "");
           client.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = (httpRequestMessage, cert, cetChain, policyErrors) =>
           {
                return true;
           };

           var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);

           request.AddHeader("Host", App.localHost);

           request.AddHeader("Accept", "*/*");

           request.AddHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");

           var response =await  client.ExecuteGetAsync<List<List<Respuesta>>>(request);
           if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
           {
                 foreach (var item in response.Data)
                 {
                      foreach (var colum in item)
                      {
                           if (colum.Columna != null)
                           {
                                if (colum.Columna.ToString() == "total")
                                {
                                    total = Convert.ToInt32(colum.Valor);
                                }
                            }
                      }
                 }
            }
       }
       catch (Exception n)
       {
           MonitorError.enviarError(n);
       }

       return total;
 }
```

Este método debo llamarlo lo mas pronto, mi pregunta es cual es la forma mas eficiente de hacer este llamado ?. Yo lo estoy llamando marcando el método appearing como async pero es esta la mejor manera o existe alguna forma mas eficiente???

```
 private async void Pagina_Appearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      Total =await servicio.obtenerPaginas("xxxxx");
 }
```

Comment: te referis al metodo OnAppearing()?

Answer (score 0):

En el caso de async y await, que acompañan a una Task, se ejecutan en el acto, a no ser que tengas una tarea anterior a la tuya que este esperando terminar para seguir con la tuya ejemplo:

```
var task = new Task.Run(() => {
                        Console.WriteLine ("Texto"}
                        Thread.Sleep(10000);
                        );

task.Wait();
```

Luego de ejecutarse task, seguira tu metodo ->

```
Pagina_Appearing(sender, e) // este no es el metodo que usa Xamarin, 
//se llama OnAppearing() y le tenes que hacer un override.



 protected override void OnAppearing()
   {
    base.OnAppearing();
   }
```

Si tienes exceso de tareas, y quieres darle prioridad a una en particular, esta lo puedes hacer creando hilos -> `thread`

```
    Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
        {

         Console.WriteLine("Esperando que se desocupe el hilo");
         Thread.Sleep(2000);
         Console.WriteLine("Hilo Desocupado");

        });
        thread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest; // le das prioridad de ejecucion.
        thread.Start();
```

Para hacer tareas e hilos y mejorar el rendimiento hay bastante para leer ya que en dos ejemplos no se cubriria el tema. Pero tambien deberias leer `Parallel` que es muy bueno y no veo que casi nadie lo use.

> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel?view=netframework-4.8